# Drawing Bitmaps Over Camera Preview

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, android-canvas

I already have a camera preview running and want to add some bitmaps over it.
And also need to move them on the screen, so far there are two options and I need help to decide which one is better:

1. ImageView -> Touch events and is easier for me.
2. Canvas -> Easier to save a picture with the preview, scale, but no touch events.

Are there more options? Which one should I use?

Comment: Have you solved it? I am facing the same issue? If any idea please reply.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Just add another SurfaceView layer ontop of the cameraPreview surfaceView , and draw your stuff there .

Comment: And how about touch events?